# Attempt to convert string variable to bool results in "true" & "false" both equal to 0

Tags: c++, if-statement, ifstream

I'm new to C++ and I am probably missing something minor but have been staring at this for way too long and would really appreciate some help.

I'm working on an assignment where the program reads in data from a CSV file. To start, I'm importing all the data in as strings using getline() because that's the only way I know how. Once imported, I want (am trying) to convert the string variables taking on "TRUE" and "FALSE" to bool types.

The CSV file contains:

```
name,color,age,wild,home,endagered
Foo,brown,3,TRUE,Malaysia,FALSE
```

Below is my code. I realize this is probably very inefficient, but I'm learning, so... it is what it is.

Here is the conversion function (it's supposed to be able to handle errors in the file):

```
void stringBool(const string & temp, bool newVar)
{
    const string fc = "FALSE";
    const string fl = "false";
    const string tc = "TRUE";
    const string tl = "true";

    try {
        if (temp==fc || temp==fl)
        {
            newVar = false;
        }
        else if (temp==tc || temp==tl)
        {
            newVar = true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw temp;
        }
    } catch (string e) {
        cout << newVar << " = " << e << " is not in the correct format. Check your file and try again." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
};
```

And here is the read-in member function for a class. It is a virtual function in a derived class if that matters. (Didn't want inundate the post with less relevant code, but please let me know if you want to see it.)

```
void readIn(std::string filename)
    {
        ifstream myFileStream(filename);

        //Error if file fails to open
        if(!myFileStream.is_open())
        {
            cout << "File failed to open" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        //Temporary strings to import
        string ag, wld, endg;
        string myString, line;

        //Read in data
        getline(myFileStream, line); //Skip first line
        while(getline(myFileStream, line))
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            getline(ss, name, ',');
            getline(ss, color, ',');
            getline(ss, ag, ',');
            getline(ss, wld, ',');
            getline(ss, home, ',');
            getline(ss, endg, ',');
        }
        myFileStream.close();

        //Convert variables from string to appropriate form
        stringBool(wld, wild);
        stringBool(endg, endanger);
        age = stoi(ag);

        //Print variables to check
    cout <<  name << endl << color << endl << age << endl << wild << endl << home << endl << endanger << endl;

    //Print temporary variables
    cout << wld << endl;
    cout << endg << endl;
    };
```

And when I actually call on the function in main, the output is:

```
Foo
brown
3
0
Malaysia
0
TRUE
FALSE
```

So even though the data have imported correctly (the strings are correct - `wld=TRUE` and `endg=FALSE`), both `wild` and `endanger` are 0.

I would be really grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please put together a [mcve]. You'll have more success if you pass `newVar` as a reference here: `stringBool(const string & temp, bool newVar)`, or simply return the value and don't pass the parameter at all so it is more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
void stringBool(const string & temp, bool newVar)
{
```

You're passing `newVar` by value. If you want changes to `newVar` to change the value in the corresponding function, it should be a reference:

```
void stringBool(const string & temp, bool& newVar)
{
```

Alternatively, just have it return the value:

```
bool stringBool(const std::string& temp) {
    if(temp == "true" || temp == "TRUE") return true;
    if(temp == "false" || temp == "FALSE") return false;
    throw std::invalid_argument("Input '" + temp + "' should be either 'true' or 'false'");
}
```

You can find `std::invalid_argument` by including `<stdexcept>`

Comment: Ok, I definitely did not understand that concept on the first pass. But why does it take on the value 0 when I have not defined it yet? Is that the default?

Comment: If you use a primitive before initializing it, you’re actually invoking UB. It might be 0, or it night be something unpredictable. That’s one of the reasons just returning a value from a function is better than modifying a reference

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if you're "using namespace std" that is generally considered a bad practise.
Secondly if you want to change a passed in variable to a function pass that variable in as a reference. Like this:

```
bool& newVar
```